# How to create flow chart using objective c for iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I need to create an app to draw an organizational chart for iPhone. user can able to chose the shapes, relationship.etc., How can do this? .Is there any library to create flow chart/org chart in objective c for iphone. 
Note: I have used coreplot for drawing pie,line,bar,scattor charts.

Comment: I believe you shouldn't ask just "how to create my app that does PING". This is a very broad question. Try to be more specific. In fact, your question is more about asking for a flow-chart building library for iOS, while title does not reflect that completely - hence, it's too broad and prone to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, it looks like an advanced coreplot but I believe you can modify this to suit your needs

[Link](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts/)